# Understanding difference in behavior between runBlocking and coroutineScope

Tags: kotlin, asynchronous, concurrency, parallel-processing, kotlin-coroutines

In the Kotlin Coroutines guide, [here](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/coroutines-basics.html#scope-builder), while explaining the difference between `runBlocking` and `coroutineScope`, it says:

> ... The main difference is that the runBlocking method blocks the current thread for waiting, while coroutineScope just suspends, releasing the underlying thread for other usages. ...

which is understandable. However, in the sample code listed there:

```
import kotlinx.coroutines.*

fun main() = runBlocking { // this: CoroutineScope
    launch { 
        delay(200L)
        println("Task from runBlocking")
    }
    
    coroutineScope { // Creates a coroutine scope
        launch {
            delay(500L) 
            println("Task from nested launch")
        }
    
        delay(100L)
        println("Task from coroutine scope") // This line will be printed before the nested launch
    }
    
    println("Coroutine scope is over") // This line is not printed until the nested launch completes
}
```

which produces the following output:

```
Task from coroutine scope
Task from runBlocking
Task from nested launch
Coroutine scope is over
```

replacing the `coroutineScope` with a `runBlocking` to be:

```
import kotlinx.coroutines.*

fun main() = runBlocking { // this: CoroutineScope
    launch { 
        delay(200L)
        println("Task from runBlocking")
    }
    
    runBlocking { // instead of coroutineScope, previously
        launch {
            delay(500L) 
            println("Task from nested launch")
        }
    
        delay(100L)
        println("Task from coroutine scope") // This line will be printed before the nested launch
    }
    
    println("Coroutine scope is over") // This line is not printed until the nested launch completes
}
```

changes nothing in the output. I expected it to produce the following output instead, since the nested `runBlocking` would block until its block finishes including all child coroutines:

```
Task from coroutine scope
Task from nested launch
Task from runBlocking
Coroutine scope is over
```

Could someone explain this behavior? What am I overseeing here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Having a runBlocking within a runBlocking is .. unusual. It's more usual that runBlocking is only the very outer thing. In fact the implementation of runBlocking will use the event loop of the outer runBlocking rather than creating a new one, so it effectively *is* behaving like coroutineScope in this case.

Source: https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx.coroutines/blob/dda99e21f45f65eb540ccf4d5e82faf7559bc9e5/kotlinx-coroutines-core/jvm/src/Builders.kt#L46

Answer (score 0):

`runBlocking` just blocks current thread until the `block` passed to it returns. It doesn't affect how the `block` is executed.

Comment: I don't see how that explains my mistake expecting the output to change!

Comment: it does it quite well actually. The `runBlocking` has no effect on the things that are inside it. Why would `task from runBlocking` (which is true for all your println, not just the first), wait for the nested runBlocking which starts after it? A runBlocking will block it's _own_ thread until it is finished. Might be easier to see if you change your println to numbers (in code order, not your expected run order).